# How to upload files to home using WinSCP .NET assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, winscp, winscp-net

I want to upload files to home (root) directory of the server, not into a folder.

How can I do it? (using C#)

```
transferResult = session.PutFiles(path, "\\", true, transferOptions);
```

If I use `\\` for `remotePath`, uploaded file was renamed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remote paths typically use Unix convention with forward-slashes, not Windows back-slashes.

Moreover using a slash only denotes a root folder, not a home folder (unless your account is chrooted).

Ideally use an absolute path to the home folder:

```
session.PutFiles(path, "/home/user/", ...);
```

For chrooted account that would be a slash only (this is a general comment, I see it's not your case):

```
session.PutFiles(path, "/", ...);
```

You can also use the `"./"` to refer to an initial (home) directory.

```
session.PutFiles(path, "./", ...);
```

You can also use the [`Session.HomePath`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session#homepath):

```
session.PutFiles(path, session.HomePath + "/", ...);
```

Comment: Awesome that the author of WinSCP is here answering questions. Probably part of the reason it works so well.